# Canceling File Encryption Windows 7

Tags: windows, encryption

I was trying to encrypt a single file, large file container of 100GB.
I clicked on the Properties --> Advanced --> Encrypt contents to secure data. However, realizing that this would not allow for on-the-fly decryption, and given the files large size, I clicked the cancel button to stop the encryption. Now the dialog box simply says: "Processing..." and has done for several hours. Given that it had only been encrypting for a few minutes, I expected a similar time frame to revers the operation. What exactly is it doing? Windows seams notorious for doing operations without stating progress or what it is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not experienced enough to state exactly what is your system doing. However from my experience with windows, I can recommend you not to attempt to terminate the process or force PC to shutdown. This _will_result in data corruption. Be patient and wait for reasonable amount of time. Even if it takes over 24 hours. Meanwhile you can try experiment with smaller files on a different machine and try to work out approximate encryption speed per Mb of data. Then use this calculations to estimate the timing for your 100GB file. Also for the worst case scenario multiply this by 2 to get process completed and then reverted and add up to 10% of margin just to be sure.

And be patient

Comment: Still going... The drive appears to be filling up as well... windows has used about 200GB, yet the size of the file it is working on has stayed the same... Could it be the disk buffer or something?

Comment: Hehehe... disaster struck... Windows explorer crashed, and the process restarted... now the file has a green label, can not be read, moved or deleted as it says "Operation cannot be completed, file open in EFS". How do i get the file released so i can delete it?

Comment: Tried rebooting PC?

Comment: Yep... Same error message, corrupted file, still locked by EFS. Seams the only option is to remove it in a third party OS, like a boot cd, or move all other data and reformat drive. Luckily this was not critical data loss, as i have older versions of the data, but still a hassle.

Comment: I would recommend to run CHKDSK with /F option to check and fix file system, and then try to remove the file from third party OS as you said.

Comment: I am baffled, after 24 hours of leaving the file there and several reboots, the file suddenly lost its green label, and could be read in its unencrypted form apparently intact...

Comment: Well, you are lucky. I think we will fail to provide technical explanation for what has happened, but hey, problem is resolved!